# Exporting Formattable

Tags: r, formattable

I made a table with the package formattable and I want to export in an image form so that I can put it in my research paper but I am not able to get the whole document out from the R studio export option.

I used this code but instead it made a web page.

I could not submit the code I tried because of the issues I have been getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the table get generated in the viewer pane, you can export it to a .pdf or a .png with Rstudio and you can control the ratio.

Comment: But the problem is my table is of much larger size and any size of ratio is not working.